# Binding Datagridview to dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem binding datagridview to dataset, when I debug code I can see that dataset is filled ok with data from database, but it wont show on datagridview...
Here is my code:

```
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        string sql = @"select artikli.idArtikla, artikli.NazivArtikla
                      from artikli";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Artikli");

        // Bind the data table to the data grid
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

EDIT: Thx for answers, now when I can see my data in grid, what is the easiest way to allow inserting, deleting and editing in my grid and forwarding those cnages to my database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` doesn't know how to bind `DataSet`, you must bind a `DataTable`.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Artikli"];
```

or

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "Artikli";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the which `DataTable` you want to bind to `DataGridView`.

Try:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to bind the dataset to gridview.

At the end of your code add the following line.. after datasource.

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataGridView is in winforms, which doesn't have `DataBind()`